# Resolution in timestamp

Tags: gps, nmea

I'm using a device with a chipset "ublox NEO-M8U" and an external antenna. I tried to write a parser for NMEA data that I received from this device, but I cannot find an answer to the question: why I don't receive milliseconds in timestamps (GNGGA/GNRMC) only always the regex looks like that **HHMMSS.00.**

Example of sentences:

```
$GNRMC,152418.00,A,6024.02224,N,00518.92204,E,0.008,,181120,1.38,E,D*35
$GNGGA,152417.00,6024.02213,N,00518.92186,E,2,12,0.85,19.2,M,43.8,M,,0000*74
```

What kind of pieces of information says me in the datasheet that I will receive (true) milliseconds in Timestamp?

Comment: What is your question? Do you refer to this document https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/NEO-M8U_DataSheet_%28UBX-15015679%29_C1-Public.pdf?

Comment: I tried to understand those data sheets, but I did not know what I'm actually searching for. My question is simply: why I don't receive milliseconds in output from GPS, is that because of a bad antenna or this chipset doesn't support millisecond in timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the NMEA output and the relevant part of the datasheet is this:

> The NEO-M8U combines GNSS and IMU measurements and calculates position
> solutions at rates of up to 2 Hz. These solutions are reported in
> standard NMEA, UBX-NAV-PVT and related messages. A new High navigation
> rate output message (UBX-HNR-PVT) extends these results with IMU-only
> data to deliver accurate, low-latency position solutions at rates of
> up to 30 Hz.

So it is possible to get NMEA messages two times per second and High navigation messages 30 times per second. For that NMEA rates two decimals is enough and `GNRMC,152418.00` means the same than `GNRMC,152418.000`. With 2 Hz frequency you should see also values like `GNRMC,152418.50` but before that you should set the frequency. By this document https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox8-M8_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_%28UBX-13003221%29.pdf the message that sets the rate is `UBX-CFG-RATE`. The default frequency seems to be 1 and the description of the message defines that the time is aligned to top zero which means that only times sec.00(0) and sec.50(0) will occur.

```
This message allows the user to alter the rate at which navigation solutions (and
the measurements that they depend on) are generated by the receiver. The
calculation of the navigation solution will always be aligned to the top of a
second zero (first second of the week) of the configured reference time system.
(Navigation period is an integer multiple of the measurement period in protocol
versions greater than 17).
• Each measurement triggers the measurements generation and, if available,
raw data output.
• The navRate value defines that every nth measurement triggers a navigation
epoch.
• The update rate has a direct influence on the power consumption. The more
fixes that are required, the more CPU power and communication resources are
required.
• For most applications a 1 Hz update rate would be sufficient.
• When using power save mode, measurement and navigation rate can differ
from the values configured here.
• See Measurement and navigation rate with power save mode for details
```

The next question is that if timestamp 152418.00 is accurate to the last digit or even to the millisecond level. That can be evaluated by reading the info about the measRate parameter (time in ms between measurements)

```
The elapsed time between GNSS measurements, which defines the rate, e.
g. 100 ms => 10 Hz, 1000 ms => 1 Hz, 10000 ms => 0.1 Hz. Measurement rate
should be greater than or equal to 25 ms.
(Measurement rate should be greater than or equal to 50 ms in protocol versions
less than 24).
```

With these capabilities I would say that even the milliseconds in the timestamp would be accurate as they can be because GPS units have good clocks, the last digit would not carry any information because the measurement itself takes 25 ms and you can't connect timestamps with milliseconds with the position at that accuracy.